# Psql and rails search with national characters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, psql

I have a problem with searching for words with national characters in psql/rails. 
Words with charters like 'ö', 'ó', 'ł', 'ü' etc - now when in db its name: 'łódź' - searching 'łódź' - its ok, but some people don't have those special charters and when search 'lodz' search returning 0 results.
I wish "Hästgård" to fit: Hästgård, Hästgard, Hastgård and/or Hastgard

How fix that problem ?
In mysql its search by collation 'utf8_unicode_ci' and its work..

Answer (score 0):

You can use a extension *unaccent*:

```
postgres=# create extension unaccent ;
CREATE EXTENSION

-- with fixed dictionary, the function can be immutable
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public._unaccent(text)
RETURNS text
LANGUAGE sql
IMMUTABLE
AS $function$ SELECT unaccent('unaccent', $1) $function$

postgres=# CREATE INDEX ON names((_unaccent(name)));
CREATE INDEX

postgres=# INSERT INTO names VALUES('Stěhule');
INSERT 0 1

postgres=# SELECT * FROM names WHERE _unaccent(name) = 'Stehule';
+---------+
|  name   |
+---------+
| Stěhule |
+---------+
(1 row)
```

When there can be more rows, then index is used:

```
postgres=# SET enable_seqscan TO off;
SET
postgres=# EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM names WHERE _unaccent(name) = 'Stehule';
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                    QUERY PLAN                                    |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Index Scan using names__unaccent_idx on names  (cost=0.12..8.14 rows=1 width=32) |
|   Index Cond: (_unaccent(name) = 'Stehule'::text)                                |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
(2 rows)
```